# Search script pagination not working

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a search script that i found online that works just fine but the pagination seems to have a problem. When I click 'Next' link nothing happens but i get this error ' Undefined variable: PHP_SELF'. What am I doing wrong? Please help.The code is below:

```
 <head>
    <title>Search pegination</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Steve R, http://www.designplace.org/">
    </head>
    <body>

    <form name="form" action="search.php" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="q" />
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

    <?php

      // Get the search variable from URL

      $var = @$_GET['q'] ;
      $trimmed = trim($var); //trim whitespace from the stored variable
      $trimmed = mysql_real_escape_string( $trimmed );
    // rows to return
    $limit=3; 

    // check for an empty string and display a message.
    if ($trimmed == "")
      {
      echo "<p>Please enter a search...</p>";
      exit;
      }

    // check for a search parameter
    if (!isset($var))
      {
      echo "<p>We dont seem to have a search parameter!</p>";
      exit;
      }

    //connect to your database ** EDIT REQUIRED HERE **
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  //(host, username, password)

    //specify database ** EDIT REQUIRED HERE **
    mysql_select_db("archivesys") or die("Unable to select database"); //select which database we're using

    // Build SQL Query  
    $query = "select * from archdetaills_tbl where archivedate like \"%$trimmed%\"  
      order by archiveid"; // EDIT HERE and specify your table and field names for the SQL query

     $numresults=mysql_query($query);
     $numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);

    // next determine if s has been passed to script, if not use 0
      if (empty($s)) {
      $s=0;
      }

    // get results
      $query .= " limit $s,$limit";
      $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");

    // display what the person searched for
    echo "<p>You searched for: &quot;" . $var . "&quot;</p>";

    // begin to show results set
    echo "Results";
    $count = 1 + $s ;

    // now you can display the results returned
      while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $title = $row["archiveeemail"];

      echo "$count.)&nbsp;$title" ;
      $count++ ;
      }

    $currPage = (($s/$limit) + 1);

    //break before paging
      echo "<br />";

      // next we need to do the links to other results
  if ($s>=1) { // bypass PREV link if s is 0
  $prevs=($s-$limit);
  print "&nbsp;<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?s=$prevs&q=$var\">&lt;&lt; 
  Prev 10</a>&nbsp&nbsp;";
  }

// calculate number of pages needing links
  $pages=intval($numrows/$limit);

// $pages now contains int of pages needed unless there is a remainder from division

  if ($numrows%$limit) {
  // has remainder so add one page
  $pages++;
  }

// check to see if last page
  if (!((($s+$limit)/$limit)==$pages) && $pages!=1) {

  // not last page so give NEXT link
  $news=$s+$limit;

  echo "&nbsp;<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?s=$news&q=$var\">Next 10 &gt;&gt;</a>";
  }

$a = $s + ($limit) ;
  if ($a > $numrows) { $a = $numrows ; }
  $b = $s + 1 ;
  echo "<p>Showing results $b to $a of $numrows</p>";

?>


<!-- © http://www.designplace.org/ -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

change `$PHP_SELF` into `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in:

```
print "&nbsp;<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?s=$prevs&q=$var\">&lt;&lt; Prev 10</a>&nbsp&nbsp;";
```

There's also several issue in your code:

- `$trimmed` should be escaped as it is a potential SQL Injection:

  ```
  $trimmed = mysql_real_escape_string( $trimmed );
  $query = "select * from archdetaills_tbl where archivedate like \"%$trimmed%\" order by archiveid";
  ```
- This code can be shortened:

  ```
  $var = @$_GET['q'] ;
  $trimmed = trim($var);
  ```

  Into:

  ```
  $trimmed = isset( $_GET['q'] ) ? trim( $_GET['q'] ) : '';
  ```

Comment: Better option is to use MySQLi and the built-in parameter binding for security.

Comment: if it solved your problem, don't forget to vote up and mark as selected answer

Comment: I made all the necessary corrections and that eliminated the error but its not loading the next values. When i ckick on the next link nothing happens. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is the correct way